# UINavigationController nested in UITabBar, select a particular index don't work

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

i have a UInavigationController nested in uitabbar and i need to push a particular view ( the second element of tabbar, index:1). (I use storyboard)

I've already tried:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBarGlobal.items objectAtIndex:1];
[tabBarGlobl setSelectedItem:tabBarItem1];
```

And for setup appearance i've used:

```
[self tabBar:self.tabBar didSelectItem:tabBarItem1];
```

The appearance is good but in the tabbar the element selected is the first and not the second.

tabBarGlobal is connected with the view in Storyboard:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBarGlobale;
```

Any Idea?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using your `UITabBar` with an `UITabBarController`, you should read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470526/using-uitabbar-without-creating-a-project-with-uitabbarcontroller) first.

And then, you have to set this `UITabBarController` property:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex)